# How to reset an AngularJs filter on init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I created a working filter that filters the data by month.

A click on a month name shows correct data. I wonder how to show **all data on page load**. Actually, **no data is shown** on page load until I click a select a month.

```
PlasmaCrm.filter('triParMois', function() {
  return function( items, mois ) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.created_at.substring(5, 7) == mois) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

I use this filter there:

```
<tr ng-repeat="finance in finances | triParMois:leMois">
```

And I set the value of leMois with a click on the motn name like this

```
<button ng-click="leMois = 01 ">Janvier</button >
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If leMois is undefined at start you could do somthing like this:

```
PlasmaCrm.filter('triParMois', function() {
  return function( items, mois ) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.created_at.substring(5, 7) == mois || angular.isUndefined(mois)) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

If it is null or some other value check for that instead.